# Jquery 1.5 Autocomplete Highligh not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-1.5

I got the following code:

```
field.autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response){
         $.getJSON('/data/autocomplete/' + param1 + "/" + param2, function(data){
             items = new Array;
             for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 datum = data[i].taxon;
                 highlighted = highlight(taxon.nombre, cadena);
                 items[i] = {
                     label: highlighted ,
                     value: datum.name,
                     id: datum.id
                 }
             }
    }                       

});

function highlight(s, t) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("("+$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(t)+")", "ig" );
    return s.replace(matcher, "<strong>$1</strong>");
}
```

It was working well:

lor for **lor**em impsum

ita for **ita**ly

but I recently updated to jQuery 1.5 and jQuery UI 1.8.10 and now it escapes characters

lor for <b>lor</b>em ipsum

ita for <b>ita</b>ly

Any ideas?

Comment: jQuery 1.9? from where did you get that

Comment: sorry...jQuery 1.5 and jQuery 1.8.10

Comment: Did you change the way your data is formatted? No reason for it to be adding line breaks like that...

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery 1.5.1. It fixed it for me after an upgrade to jQuery 1.5 gave getElementsByTagName errors for autocomplete in IE.